# MOV r, M instruction in 8085 microprocessor

Tags: assembly, mov, 8085

I am sorry if the question is too basic but I still cannot understand the code that I found in Google. Basically, I need to make a simple code of `MOV r, M` instruction in 8085 microprocessor.

Here is the code that I want to make:

```
LXI H, 1234H
MOV B, M
HLT
```

My question is the code correct? What is the result of the code after it get executed? Does the `B` contain 1234H data now? Or the result does not have any content in `E` because there is no value specified in 1234H memory?  Really appreciate for any help or guidance, thanks.

Comment: `LXI H, 1234H` loads the immediate value (an address in this case) to the `HL` register pair. `MOV B, M` moves the byte from memory address pointed to by the `HL` register pair and puts it in the `B` register

Comment: @MichaelPetch But for the code above, there is no value in B right after it get executed? Because I have not specified any value for memory 1234H, is this correct from my understanding?

Comment: There will be a value at memory address `1234h` but it is garbage (could be any value) if you haven't put anything there to begin with.

Comment: @MichaelPetch ah understand. So, for the code above, it should be all correct already? Do I need to initialize the value in adress 1234H? If yes, can I use command MVI H, 38H?

Comment: `MVI H, 38H` just moves the immediate value `38H` into the 8-bit register `H`. To initialize memory address 1234h with `38H` you could do `LXI H, 1234H` `MVI M, 38H`

Comment: Ah now I got it. I just run the code in the 8085 simulator with the MVI M, 38H and now I can see that the register B have the value 38H. Thankyou so much @MichaelPetch for your help. Really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After execution of the above code, the register B contains the content of the memory location 1234H.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Perhaps you could go into a bit more detail, what each instruction does, see e.g. Michael Petch's first comment.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).